# Display: table-cell image and text on single line (responsive design)

Tags: css, responsive-design, overflow, css-tables

I want to have list item that has a profile picture in the left hand side and Name in the right hand side. The name should be on a single line with `overflow:hidden`.

How can this be done with responsive widths and heights? I managed to do this with pixels but not with %.

Example:
[image: example]

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/NjqpC/

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.first {
  width: 8%;
  height: 3%;
}
.second {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.third {
  border: .1em solid;
  font-size: .8em;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: table;
}
.third img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
}
.third span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow:hidden;
}

<div class='first'>
  <ul class='second'>
    <li class='third'>
      <img src='http://static.wikiartis.com/img/profile-small.gif'>
      <span>First-Surname Family-name</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the class third, add "white-space: nowrap"

```
.third {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The class containing the width and height needs to get an overflow: hidden

```
.first {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

In this case, that is the div.first.

To get the image working as well, I gave all parents a height. 100% for every parent other than first.

I gave the img the following styling:

```
.third img {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NjqpC/4/)

By adding white-space: nowrap; you tell the text it may not wrap over multiple lines. So that means the text will always stay on the same line. [source](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)

Comment: Yeah it makes the text go on a single line, but overflow: hidden is still not working

Comment: Sorry, read over that part. I updated the fiddle and the answer.

Comment: Overflow now works, but for some reason the image is not showing. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Do you want the image to resize along with the rest of the page? Otherwise you just need to set dimensions for the image.
If those dimensions need to be in percentages as well, let me know. I'll fix something for that then.

Comment: Yes I want the image to resize with the page. Therefore the dimensions need to be in percentages.